# Is it possible for Firebase to alert me based on a certain event parameter?

Tags: firebase

I have an event from my Android app on Firebase that if it reaches a certain value I would like to be notified. Is this possible with Firebase?

Basically the event sends a string with what happened on a certain service request. If the service request failed it sends a certain string. I want to be alerted when that certain string is more than 10% of all events. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a cloud function that is listing for events into the collection/doc you are interested in... when you get the error, you write to this collection lets say it is called `WHATEVER_COLLECTION_YOUR_ARE_GOING_TO_LISTING_TO`

It would look something like (i dont know your specific case, this is only to get you started):

```
 import * as functions from 'firebase-functions' 
 import * as admin from 'firebase-admin' 
 const firestore = admin.firestore()

  const counter = firestore.document(`WHATEVER_COLLECTION_YOUR_ARE_GOING_TO_LISTING_TO/{doc}`).onUpdate(async (change, _context) => {
    const newData = change.after
    const data = newData.data()

    if (data.MYSTRING === 'SOMETHING HAPPENED IT IS MORE THAN 10%') {
        // USE SENDGRID OR TWILIO OR WHATEVER TO NOTIFY ME
    }

    return Promise.resolve(true)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this require enabling anything special on Google's cloud, like BigQuery or similar?

Comment: nope :) you are good to go with the default